# laravel 5.7 "Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider' not found"

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

On my localhost is fine, but when i upload on my server i got this error:

```
"Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider' not found"
```

My config/app.php:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
    ..

],
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,

],
```

my laravel version is 5.7

Comment: How do you use it in your controller? Please note that this is a case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `composer dump-autoload` in your command line

Comment: where i run it? hosted or localhost?

Comment: run it where you have the issue.